# Using GDB debug info in a separate file

Tags: gdb

I stumbled upon this article http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html#Separate-Debug-Files

But it says this can be only done for executables, or in exact words

Any executable file format can carry a debug link, as long as it can contain a section named .gnu_debuglink with the contents described above.

I wanted to check if I can separate the debug info for my shared binary .so files as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The manual is somewhat unclear here.  The phrase "any executable file format" actually means "anything gdb understands, whether it be an executable or a shared library".

In fact, many distros -- for example, Fedora -- split the debuginfo for nearly every package into a separate package; and this is done for both executables and shared libraries.